# PyQt model/view for QLineEdit...the simplest case

Tags: model, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm finding a lot of tutorials online illustrating model/view techniques for widgets like combo boxes and list views that use QAbstractStingList, but I can't find anything on how to bind a model to something super-simple like a QLineEdit? What do I use as the model in this case where the model is simply a string variable that needs to be synchronized with the view?

Comment: After some more hunting around I believe what I'm looking for is the "QDataWidgetMapper" object. I'll start there.

Comment: QLineEdit combines a widget and a model both in one.